# AwsGlueCrawlerOperator config dictionary

Tags: aws-glue, airflow

So I am trying to start a Glue crawler from my DAG and waiting for it to complete before I proceed with my workflow. Cant figure out what Airflow expects in the config argument.

Here is my code:

```
run_crawler = AwsGlueCrawlerOperator(task_id="run_crawler",
                                                 aws_conn_id=aws_secret, config={???},
                                                 crawler_name ="name_of_crawler",
                                                 poll_interval=60, priority_weight=3)
```

Initially, I entered `{"crawler_name":"name_of_crawler", "iam_role":"iam_role_name}` with other settings constant. However it complained about me referencing crawler name in the dictionary. Took that out and still no dice.

Does anyone know what goes in the config dictionary for this operator or alternatively initiate a glue crawler from local docker instance on aws account? I have the credentials in a Connection that I am referencing in the variable aws_secret.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/975a4e05c98803ce8491d9422516ccb04611082e/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/glue_crawler.py#L67) it looks like the name in `config` should be under `Name` key not `crawler_name`. Also I think this operator does not accept `crawler_name` argument which you pass in your example.

Comment: You're right. Turns out I also need to remove the IAM reference. And instead also add the following in the **extras** of my AWS Connection in airflow - `{"region":"my_region", "role_arn":"arn of the IAM Service Role that created the crawler"}`. Then go into AWS IAM, find the service role mentioned here and set up a Trust relationship to the ARN of the user (you or the DAG creator) whose Access Key and Secret is used in the Airflow Connection to AWS. Then back to airflow, clear the errored out task and let it rerun.

Comment: In the IAM section, I'm thinking its better to assign trust relationship to a group to which you can add users like DAG Authors or Data Engineers....